# Traducción más apropiada para el término 'casserole' del inglés

Tags: traducción

Siempre había pensado que el término *casserole* del inglés debía traducirse como *cacerola* pero hace poco descubrí que son falsos amigos. El equivalente más acertado que encontré para el último término es *pot* o *saucepot*, pero ¿cómo se traduciría el primer término?

Cuando googleo imágenes para *casserole* me aparecen fotos de *fuentes* planas y poco profundas—como las que se usan para cocinar pastel de papa—o bien me aparecen recipientes más profundos—que en ese caso serían a mi entender *bowls o boles*.

¿Alguien sabe si hay algún término de nuestro idioma que sea el que mejor se aproxime a la palabra? Sé que la etimología de dicha palabra es francesa y, [por lo visto](http://www.ikonet.com/fr/ledictionnairevisuel/alimentation-et-cuisine/cuisine/batterie-de-cuisine.php), en tal idioma la misma sí se traduciría como 'cacerola'. Pero pregunto específicamente por el uso que se le da en el inglés. ¿O acaso será que el criterio en el que se basan los angloparlantes para hacer tal denominación se debe no a la forma del recipiente, si no al uso que se le da al mismo—el tipo de platos que se cocinan? ¿Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: cacerola es un tipo de fuente. Pero, casserole es  un plato típico americano. Una tarta hecha en un plato o pyrex  hondo que se cocina en el horno. No existe en Europa o América Latina realmente. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casserole#Other_cuisines

Comment: algo parecido: https://www.bonviveur.es/recetas/arroz-al-horno [Arriba, una especie de tarta, y no una tarta en si]. Por lo general, es una pasta con carne y legumbres en una cacerola, cocido al horno y con parmesan. El más conocido de todos: tuna fish casserole.

Comment: Pero de acuerdo al artículo de Wikipedia: "A casserole [...] is **a kind of large, deep pan or bowl** used for cooking a variety of dishes in the oven; **it is also a category of foods** cooked in such a vessel". Y de acuerdo a tu comentario, entonces entiendo que la acepción principal de la palabra refiere al alimento y que la acepción para nombrar al recipiente es derivada de la comida.

Comment: Sí, pero en terminos de comida no es el recipiente, es un tipo de comida. A casserole dish is usually a rectangular dish with high sides.  Los franceses llaman ese metodo de cocinar pasta con queso etc: cassoulet pero en platitos chicos. Es curioso porque las comidas que se hacen así son muy popular y no muy fino y se parece a algo casi campesino. Por eso nunca entendí porque no se encuentra en España y Francia de la misma forma.

Comment: I would have used casserole both for the utensil and for the dish cooked in it. It should have a cover and, presumably to get a tight fit, the utensil is usually round or oval. The dish cooked in it would usually have some liquid left in it when it is served. When I was a child I think we probably called the food a stew but casserole sounds more grand. This is in south-east England. Many of the images of food on the internet seem to be of US casseroles which look different.

Answer (score 5):

En español tenemos la palabra "**cazuela**" que puede tratar tanto de un utensilio para cocinar y que habitualmente es un recipiente de barro de base generalmente circular, y aunque existen, es menos común el tipo alargado, poco profundo, si bien también los he encontrado fabricados de metal. Igualmente "cazuela" (cazuela de...) puede ser referido a un tipo de guiso o plato típico gastronómico hecho y presentado dentro del recipiente, normalmente carne, patatas, mariscos, legumbres..

- Cazuela

https://dle.rae.es/cazuela

- Cazuela Comida

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cazuela_(comida)

Comment: No es el nombre de una comida como casserole. Dicimos casserole **dish** para el recipiente. Y los casseroles se cocinan en pyrex.

Comment: @Lambie en el segundo enlace de wikipedia que ha puesto sí es una comida.

Comment: En Reino Unido es una comida https://www.bbc.co.uk/food/casserole.

Comment: @geofisue En inglés, es **sobretodo una comida**. Cuando es una fuente, solemos decir: casserole dish, the receptacle. Pero bueno, casserole dish is medio ambiguo. En español, este tipo de comida no existe en si. Y las cazuelas en Wikipedia no están hechas con pasta + algo y cocinadas en el horno.